# TextViews clipped in Dynamic GridLayout (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

I'm using a GridLayout (from the support library, if that matters) into which I dynamically add TextViews. I here get a problem with all TexViews getting added in only one row, which also leads to some of them not showing and the last one shown to get clipped.

How can I solve this so that it places the TextViews in the next row.

This is my GridLayout definition:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_views"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/another_layout"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@color/soft" />
```

Comment: I have had this problem with the support library GridLayout.  When I used stock GridLayout (target 14+) instead, it worked fine.  Remember to specify android:columnCount and 
        android:orientation

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the number of columns you want, either dynamically using method call or in xml definition ( android:numColumns="2").

Comment: So if I want to do it dynamically, I have to programatically find out how many TextViews that can fit into one row of the GridLayout? What's the purpose of the GridLayout then, if it can't do it itself?